# When I merge a branch with my current one, should that add files to my working copy?

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm using Git and I created a branch B2 from a branch B1. Changes were made to B1 so I merged B1 into my B2. My working copy was clean before this merge. Now, after the merge I suddenly have files in my working copy. Is this normal? I'm new to Git. Now I have to commit this change but I'm not the one who made these changes so what do I put as description to the commit if this is the normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
All committed files in current branch will direct reflect in working directory.

Working directory is virtually manage by GIT, and put changes base on branch you are currently checked out.

So you have pulled(by merging from b2) all new changes from branch B2 to your branch B1, and your are currently in b1 branch then new changes will reflect in working directory as its now part of branch b1 after merge.

Usually merge need, when need to test changes in branch b1 with any other branch changes that will go live to-gather.